# Python "dict" as state/context for ParDo function

Tags: python, apache-beam

How can I write a ParDo function with some state (a max heap) and timers, such that every timer-trigger, I can peek/pop the 'timed out' values from the heap and yield them into downstream stream processing nodes/ParDo functions?

So to be clear; I want everything streaming, with a "global" window, if you so wish, and triggers/timers that let me output intermediate state (and clean it up continuously as well). Could you give me an example of state+timer in python that does this?

Research done:

- session windows are fairly broken, or so hard to use, I haven't been able to make them work; but the algorithm accuracy I care about is simple enough as long as I can have timers, state and the low-water-mark available to me
- docs say it's not supported, but the issue tracker says it is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2687 and https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/6349/files and https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/6433/commits/cf85ded024d27f20ccedb3c135b5e8e785285aec indicate it's been done, as well; but since this is my first python, it's hard for me to determine how to write it even with the test examples